# Changing comma in \textcite to colon

Tags: biblatex

This should be really simple, but I can't find the answer.  I want to use \textcite with authoryear style, but replace the comma after the year by a colon; that is, have Nichols (2004: 13) instead of Nichols (2004, 13).  Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone} %
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} %
\usepackage{filecontents} %

\addbibresource{example.bib} %

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@Article{nichols04,
author =       {Nichols, Shaun},
title =        {After Objectivity: An Empirical Study of Moral Judgment},
journal =      {Philosophical Psychology},
year =         {2004},
volume =       {17},
number =       {1},
pages =        {3--26}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

As described in \textcite[13]{nichols04}.
\end{document}
```

I have already removed the p. with `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`.  I have also omitted `\printbibliography`, since I'm **not** interested in modifying the bibliography, but the citation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an error in the manual which makes this hard to find. The macro described as defining punctuation after the post-note actually seems to define punctuation before the post-note.

At least, redefining it seems to work.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{nichols04,
author =       {Nichols, Shaun},
title =        {After Objectivity: An Empirical Study of Moral Judgment},
journal =      {Philosophical Psychology},
year =         {2004},
volume =       {17},
number =       {1},
pages =        {3--26}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}
\renewcommand\postnotedelim{\addcolon\addspace}


\begin{document}

As described in \textcite[13]{nichols04}.
\end{document}
```

[image: redefined post-note delimiter]

Comment: The description is fixed now: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/154c1ead4b69ce44430eec7e514d267589f02a7e (I hope that is what you referred to). In fact `\postnotdelim` is documented twice. The description in the user guide part of the manual was OK, the problem was in the author guide bit. I'm beginning to doubt it makes sense to duplicate the information. It is probably enough to have it only once.