# Reprogramming postnote to refer to example numbers and ranges (Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, examples

When using `\cite` or `\textcite`, I like to give, as part of the postnote-dedicated optional argument, additionally to the page range, some example number(s), for example `ex. 38`.

I am seeking to program a postnote `postnote:examples` that would allow me to pass the example number(s) or ranges and include judicious delimitations: ideally, a semicolon would be great to associate a range of examples to the page range, and the initial comma could be replaced with a colon.

I would like the `p./pp.` prefix to be used. (As seen in the MWE, right now, when adding more stuff into  the postnote than only the pages, the prefix is not supported.)

Also, I need an **and** instead of a comma inside the last couple of page or example numbers.

For example,

```
\textcite[45-52,63-65:3-6;57-68:21-23;72-74:3-5,7-9]{ref}
```

would display :

```
author (year: pp. 45-52 and 63-65, ex. 3-6; pp. 57-68, ex. 21-23; pp. 72-74, ex. 3-5 and 7-9).
```

The thing is, I kind of know how to split optional arguments in some specific cases, I have seen in a couple of posts how to pass a infinite list of elements, I can program a cite command by looking at a model, but the three of them at the same time is beyond my skill level, I'm afraid.

**EDIT**

After `moewe`'s answer, it appears that supporting the **and** between the last two page or example numbers, while keeping the `p./pp.` introducer, would require too much tweaking.

Can someone provide a way to get this **and**, even dropping the `p./pp.` ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[citestyle=ext-authoryear-comp,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\newcommand{\exmp}[1]{\unskip,\space ex.\@\,#1}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    
    @book{smi96,
        author = {Smith, Adam},
        year = {1996},
        title = {Economy},
        publisher = {My company} 
    }
    

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}

\textcite[54]{smi96}

\textcite[54\exmp{32}]{smi96}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would be much more productive if you could comment *why* you vote down, I'm a beginner and if you don't say WHAT you are criticizing, your vote is completely pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an unholy combination of `xparse`, `expl3`, LaTeX2e and `biblatex` trickery.

Step one is obviously to split the input at the semicolons. Then we need to separate the bits before and after the colon. The bit before the colon is printed with `biblatex`'s usual `\mkpageprefix` (so responds to the `pagination` field). The bit after the colon is also printed with `\mkpageprefix`, but we fake the value `example` for the `pagination` field so that we get to see "ex." for the example.

This solution does not add an "and" between page ranges, because it delegates typesetting of page ranges to `biblatex`, which just separates different ranges with commas.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-comp,]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{example}
\NewBibliographyString{examples}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  example  = {ex\adddot},
  examples = {ex\adddot},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\ppexformat{#1}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_vk_ppex_chunks

\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat{m}{\vk_ppex_chunk:n{#1}}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \vk_ppex_chunk:n #1
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vk_ppex_chunks ; {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_vk_ppex_chunks
    {
      \int_compare:nNnT {##1} > {1}
        {\addsemicolon\space}
      \ppexformat@splitchunk {##2}
    }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat@splitchunk{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{%
  \ppexformat@ppex #1}
  
\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat@ppex{mm}{%
  \mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}%
  \IfNoValueF{#2}
    {\addcomma\space
     \exformat{#2}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\exformat}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \def\abx@field@pagination{example}%
    \mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite[54]{sigfridsson}

\textcite[54:32]{sigfridsson}

\textcite[45-52,63-65:3-6;57-68:21-23;72-74]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998, pp. 45–52, 63–65, ex. 3–6; pp. 57–68, ex. 21–23; pp. 72–74)]

Comment: @VincentKrebs Not without a lot more pain, because you would have to re-do `biblatex`'s list parsing to inject the "and". It wouldn't be too hard to just redo the list formatting bit in `expl3`, but you'd also have to re-do the "p."/"pp." distinction, which I don't want to do.

Comment: I see, I thought maybe biblatex had a special option for this.

Comment: @VincentKrebs I didn't address the colon after the year, because that is discussed elsewhere, e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433122/35864

Comment: Or better https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/619985/35864

Comment: Oh well yes it's just one line to add `\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}`. thanks.

Comment: @VincentKrebs I rejected the edit, because I'd rather have the answer focus on the relevant bit of the question. The colon is basically a FAQ and would only distract from the already pretty long code.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Editing the question after you've gotten an answer and invalidating existing answers is usually not a great move. In this case though, if you prefer the output you have in the question now and don't want to lose the "advertising power" of the bounty, I could just delete this answer and leave it be.

Comment: @VincentKrebs Your call. Normally, I'd say just ask a new question and keep this one as it was before it was answered. But since this is a bountied question I wanted to give you the option of not losing the bounty on an answer you are no longer interested in.

Comment: Ok I see, I edited my question in this spirit. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is there away to get `\mknormrange` to support letters as in ex. 22b ? If I put a letter, the "ex." disappears. Thanks!

Comment: @VincentKrebs `\DeclareNumChars*{abc}` will make `a`, `b` and `c` pass tests like `\ifnumeral`. If you put all letters from `a` to `z` though, this becomes pointless since that would make arbitrary text pass as a number.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much. If I understand correctly, we cant limit range of this declaration by incorporating it into the \ppex command ?