# Biblatex Postnote: adding *and* between the last two ranges

Tags: biblatex, page

Using `moewe`'s answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/675579/262813) I can add example numbers and ranges to the postnote of `Biblatex` cite commands.

`moewe`'s code is perfect since it uses `\mknormrange` directly, which is all one can dream of in terms of compatibility with the various package options.

How could one program a variant `\mknormrangewithand` so as to add **and** between the last two page or example ranges?

Simple example (with pages only):

`\cite[17-20,24-27,38-40]{ref}` would output:

`author (year: pp. 17-20,24-27 **and** 38-40)`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authoryear-comp,]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{example}
\NewBibliographyString{examples}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    example  = {ex\adddot},
    examples = {ex\adddot},
}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\ppexformat{#1}}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_vk_ppex_chunks

\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat{m}{\vk_ppex_chunk:n{#1}}

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \vk_ppex_chunk:n #1
{
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_vk_ppex_chunks ; {#1}
    \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_vk_ppex_chunks
    {
        \int_compare:nNnT {##1} > {1}
        {\addsemicolon\space}
        \ppexformat@splitchunk {##2}
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat@splitchunk{>{\SplitArgument{1}{:}}m}{%
    \ppexformat@ppex #1}

\NewDocumentCommand\ppexformat@ppex{mm}{%
    \mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}%
    \IfNoValueF{#2}
    {\addcomma\space
        \exformat{#2}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\exformat}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \def\abx@field@pagination{example}%
    \mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    \textcite[54]{sigfridsson}
    
    \textcite[54:32]{sigfridsson}
    
    \textcite[45-52,63-65:3-6;57-68:21-23;72-74]{sigfridsson} % I want "and" between "45-52" and "63-65".

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In line 59, I have simply written

```
\textcite[45-52 and 63-65:3-6;57-68:21-23;72-74]{sigfridsson}
```

with this result:

[image]

Comment: You lose the prefix. The whole point is that you cannot put whatever you like inside the post note without losing the formatting. See the post linked.